# Big Oh notation involving $\log n!\in O(n\log n)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I have worked hard on these questions and have found my own approach. I'm just checking if it makes logical sense for others and works. I'd appreciate any hints or better approaches.

Question 1: Prove that $\log n!\in O(n\log n)$

My Approach:

Assuming $\log n!\in O(n\log n)$

Then there must exist a case where there is a constant $c > 0$ and $k$ where $logn! < c ∗ nlogn$ for every $n > k$.

Consider when $c = 1$, then there should be a case where $logn! < 1 ∗ nlogn$ is true.

Suppose $k = 0$ then $logn!$ $ϵ$ $O(nlogn)$ since the inequality $logn! < 1 ∗ nlogn$ holds true for every case of $n > k$

Comment: You start trying to prove $\log n!\in O(n\log n)$ by saying "Since $\log n!\in O(n\log n)$, ..." which does not make sense.

Comment: How does it not make sense? It means " since $logn!$ grows slower than $nlogn$" then i must proof this...

Comment: The word "since" means that the sentence following it is known to be true. The sentence "$\log n!$ grows slower than $n\log n$" is not known to be true: it's what you're supposed to show is true! The approach you've taken doesn't work at all. I'd suggest starting with something simpler, say, $n+5\in O(n^2)$. Your complexity argument is correct for the first program in the second problem, but you should take the rest, which is computer science, to the corresponding stackexchange site.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. But how is my question 1 completely wrong? I checked the inequality for every n ∈ N and that constant works and the inequality is satisfied.

Comment: Also, I will remove Question 2 and leave question 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of a correct proof would be:

$$\log n!=\sum_{i=1}^n{\log i}\leq \sum_{i=1}^n{\log n}=n\log n$$

so $\log n!\in O(n\log n)$ since $\log n!\leq n\log n$ for all $n$.

Comment: Well I understand the part where $logn!$ $=$ $\sum_{i=1}^n{\log i}$  But how does $\sum_{i=1}^n{\log i}\leq \sum_{i=1}^n{\log n}$ mean it equals $nlogn$?

Comment: doesn't it just mean log1 = log1 when i = 1 for both summations? Iteratively i don't understand how it equals to $n * logn$

Comment: There are two different statements. $\sum_{i=1}^n{\log i}\leq \sum_{i=1}^n{\log n}$, and $\sum_{i=1}^n{\log n}=n\log n$, the second because it is a sum of $\log n$ with itself $n$ times. This is not equal to $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\log i}$.

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^n{\log n}$ does not include the variable $i$ in the calculation. So when $i++$ and $i = 2$, what happens? Because $n$ does not change so I understand if $n=4$ then $\sum_{i=1}^4{\log n}$ = log4

Comment: All I'm really confused on is, where does $n$ multiply $logn$ in the summation?

Comment: For example, $\sum_{i=1}^3{\log 3}=\log 3+\log 3+\log 3=3\log 3$.

Comment: Wow, that makes a lot more sense thanks a lot. Now I understand what I did wrong initially thanks for the help Matt.

Comment: @geforce You're welcome.

Comment: More directly, $log(n!) \leq log(n^n)$. By rule of logs, we get $log(n^n) = nlog(n)$.